# Error calculating odds ratio in R using oddsratio() from epitools

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the odds ratios for levels of exposure to a risk factor on anxiety rate, for the data generated by:

```
data<-structure(list(exposure = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("mild", 
"severe", "unaffected"), class = "factor"), count_not_anxious = c(108, 
337, 203), count_anxious = c(8, 48, 76)), .Names = c("exposure", 
"count_not_anxious", "count_anxious"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like:

```
    exposure count_not_anxious count_anxious
1 unaffected               108             8
2       mild               337            48
3     severe               203            76
```

I arranged the data specifically for use with the oddsratio() function from the 'epitools' package, however `oddsratio(data)` generates the following error message:

```
Error in nrow(x) : object 'x' not found
```

Why is this? Have I just misunderstood how the data should be arranged for this function?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can do this by converting the data from a three-column data frame to a two-row matrix ...

```
> dd <- as.matrix(data[,-1])  ## drop first column
> rownames(dd) <- data[,1]
> oddsratio(dd)
```

Results:

```
$data
           count_not_anxious count_anxious Total
unaffected               108             8   116
mild                     337            48   385
severe                   203            76   279
Total                    648           132   780

$measure
                        NA
odds ratio with 95% C.I. estimate    lower    upper
              unaffected 1.000000       NA       NA
              mild       1.891296 0.911011  4.46757
              severe     4.956366 2.432386 11.56705

$p.value
            NA
two-sided      midp.exact fisher.exact   chi.square
  unaffected           NA           NA           NA
  mild       9.001770e-02 1.289249e-01 9.505682e-02
  severe     1.579224e-06 1.755645e-06 6.787096e-06

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "median-unbiased estimate & mid-p exact CI"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried removing the exposure column previously but it didn't work until I coerced it into a matrix rather than a data frame!